# How to convert calendar date to ldap date

Tags: java, spring, calendar, ldap

Currently I have tried this code, but the problem is the first line of code gives this output 20150217172651+0100 and my required output is 20150217172651.0Z

```
GeneralizedTime gt = new GeneralizedTime(Calendar.getInstance());       
    String gtADString = gt.toGeneralizedTime(
            GeneralizedTime.Format.YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR_MIN_SEC,
            GeneralizedTime.FractionDelimiter.DOT, 1,
            GeneralizedTime.TimeZoneFormat.Z).replaceFirst("Z", "\\.0Z");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran your code

```
public class poc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeneralizedTime gt = new GeneralizedTime(Calendar.getInstance());
        String gtADString = gt.toGeneralizedTime(
                GeneralizedTime.Format.YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR_MIN_SEC,
                GeneralizedTime.FractionDelimiter.DOT, 1,
                GeneralizedTime.TimeZoneFormat.Z).replaceFirst("Z", "\\.0Z");
        System.out.println(gtADString);

    }
}
```

And got this as output:

> 20150217163832.0Z

Using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-util</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-M28</version>
</dependency>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follow:

```
long t1 = calenderObj.getTimeInMillis();
calenderObj.set(1601, 0, 1);
long t2 = calenderObj.getTimeInMillis();
long ldap = (t1 - t2) * 10000;
```

Hope this would help.